# mongodb design polymorphic vs embedded

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql, polymorphism

I am thinking to create users collection which consists of only two types of users; teacher and students.

```
Users {
    name: String,
    dob: Date,
    subjectsTaught: Array,
    department: String,
    grades: Array,
    classroom: String,
}
```

This is the standard way of polymorphism, right? Another developer suggests to do like that.

```
Users {
    name: String,
    dob: Date,
    studentInfo: {
        grades: Array,
        classroom: String,
    },
    teacherInfo: {
        subjectsTaught: Array,
        department: String,
    },
}
```

I can't explain why my approach is the right way to do it. What are the pros and cons of these two schemas?

Answer (score 0):

Second one seams better to me, as it specialize the entity and only data which concern both of the children are being handle by the `Users` Entity.
The CDM would be something like that

- `USER(id, name, dob)`
- `STUDENT(id_user, grades, classroom)` where id_user is foreign key references USER.id
- `TEACHER(id_user, subjectTaught, department` where id_user is foreign key references USER.id

Then the object would be quite the same as those entity.

Of course `subjectsTaught` and `grades` might be store into separated table as they are array data. But as this is not your question and this is not conceptual level, i'll not abord that here.